# How to get EnvDte.DTE in an assembly referenced by a T4 Template

Tags: visual-studio, t4

In an assembly referenced by a T4 template using the `<#@ assembly #>` directive, I execute the code `var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));` which results in the following exception and stack trace.

```
Error   1   Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProjectName.TextTemplating, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MyProjectName.TextTemplating, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at MyProjectName.TextTemplating.MyProjectNameTextTransformation.GetCurrentProject() in C:\Users\n1200632d\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DataAccessLayerTests\MyProjectName.TextTemplating\MyProjectNameTextTransformation.cs:line 123
```

Answer (score 0):

In the referenced assembly toggling the ComVisible assembly attribute either through the project's assembly properties or directly in the AssemblyInfo code file using the attribute `[assembly: ComVisible(..)]` appears to resolve the exception.

Comment: I think EnvDTE is not part of the GAC, so I would rather check if it gets deployed to the right place (wherever you run your application), instead of fiddling with ComVisible.

Comment: @CsabaToth, the attribute being toggled is for the assembly being referenced by the T4 template, NOT for EnvDTE which is part of Visual Studio.  It is an odd behavior given that the problem goes away merely by toggling this property.